# I cannot include an image in a TCPDF header

Tags: tcpdf

To create a custom header and footer, I used TCPDF's `header()` and `footer()` functions, but when I try to include an image in the header using the function `$this->image()`, the image cannot be displayed. Other images in the document are working fine.

Answer (score 14):

Try this example:

```
$pdf->SetHeaderData("image.jpg", PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, "Application PDF", "Application Form\nRaining Pesos, Inc. - www.rainingpesos.com");
```

The first parameter is where you put the image on the header, but make sure on your path image config,

```
define ('K_PATH_IMAGES', '/images/');
```

make sure the images that you want to display on the pdf is in the folder you set, in this example the folder 'images' contains the 'image.jpg'.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Manie, 

Thanks,My problem is solved with the use of .png or .gif images 
you can put either png or gif image for custom header for custom footer no need to write custom footer function its working as usual 

Thanks,
Once again